# Setting large json file to Firebase with specific key for each item

Tags: json, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Keen for your advice on the best approach. I have a large json file that I want to set to firebase that currently has array of items like below:

```
{
"features": [
    {
        "properties": {
            "key": "2345345",
            "data1": "data",
            "data2": "data",
            "data3": "data"
        }
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "key": "3455647",
            "data1": "data",
            "data2": "data",
            "data3": "data"
        }
    }
]
}
```

However, firebase will auto generate a key for each object. I would like to be able to set the key myself, using the key in the properties so it would look like this:

```
{
"features": {
   "2345345": {
        "properties": {
            "key": "2345345",
            "data1": "data",
            "data2": "data",
            "data3": "data"
        }
    },
    "3455647": {
        "properties": {
            "key": "3455647",
            "data1": "data",
            "data2": "data",
            "data3": "data"
        }
    }
}
}
```

It is for an Angular 2 web project using angularfire2.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I don't have control over the way the data is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and change it to an object.

```
let obj = {features: [...]};

var new_features = {};
for(var i=0; i<obj.features.length; i++) {
    var key = ... // <- create your own key here
    new_features[key] = obj.features[0];
}
obj.features = new_features;
const items = db.object('/features');
items.set(obj);
```

OR set each object separately (involves more calls)

```
for(var i=0; i<obj.features.length; i++) {
    var key = ... // <- create your own key here
    const items = db.object('/features/' + key);
    items.set(obj.features[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @theblindprophet. Works well!